# Does passing many props to different child components affect my app's performance?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I started learning React recently and managed to build a simple application. The app works well, but I ended up passing too many props to child components, which makes the code very messy. I was looking for ways to improve my code and found out that there are different ways to handle the state of my application. Most of my research pointed to either Redux or the useContext hook.

Besides making my code cleaner, does Redux or useContext help improve the performance of my application? Or are they actually worse than passing props when it comes to performance?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is a bit general, Could you provide your current works so everyone can have some data to analyze from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redux in itself isn't really slowing your App down if you do it right. What may cause your app to slow down is too many re-renders. Here is an article on how to prevent that : https://redux.js.org/faq/performance#wont-calling-all-my-reducers-for-each-action-be-slow

You can also read about performance in the offical Redux documentation: https://redux.js.org/faq/performance#wont-calling-all-my-reducers-for-each-action-be-slow

and this: [https://redux.js.org/faq/general#:~:text=Redux%20is%20most%20useful%20when%20in%20cases%20when%3A&text=The%20app%20state%20is%20updated,is%20being%20updated%20over%20time](https://redux.js.org/faq/general#:%7E:text=Redux%20is%20most%20useful%20when%20in%20cases%20when%3A&text=The%20app%20state%20is%20updated,is%20being%20updated%20over%20time)

A slight downside to redux and useContext, is that you have to wait for the redux store to be available on the initial render, so you have to check if the state is available before using it. `(state && console.log(state)`. However, this is still better than passing around a million props.